# PHP strtotime() outputs nothing

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime

Here is my PHP code:

```
echo '<br />1. '.$w_time_no;
echo '<br />2. '.strtotime($w_time_no);
echo '<br />3. '.date('G:i', strtotime($w_time_no));
```

That's what I get:

```
1. 0000-00-00 22:00:00
2.
3. 2:00
```

Why strtotime() outputs nothing by itself? Is there something wrong with server settings? Server: Apache/2.2.11 (Win32), PHP 5.2.10, MySQL client version: 5.0.51a.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`strtotime` doesn't "output" anything, btw : it returns `false` in case of an error ; see the [manual](http://php.net/strtotime) :

> **Return Values**
>
> Returns a timestamp on success, FALSE
>   otherwise. Previous to PHP 5.1.0, this
>   function would return -1 on failure.

What doesn't output anything is `echo` : `false` is considered as an empty string, and nothing get outputed.

strtotime's documentation also gives the valid range for dates :

> Note: The valid range of a timestamp
>   is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901
>   20:45:54 UTC to Tue, 19 Jan 2038
>   03:14:07 UTC. (These are the dates
>   that correspond to the minimum and
>   maximum values for a 32-bit signed
>   integer.) Additionally, not all
>   platforms support negative timestamps,
>   therefore your date range may be
>   limited to no earlier than the Unix
>   epoch. This means that e.g. dates
>   prior to Jan 1, 1970 will not work on
>   Windows, some Linux distributions, and
>   a few other operating systems. PHP
>   5.1.0 and newer versions overcome this limitation though.

`'0000-00-00'` is outside of this range, so it's not considered a valid date ; hence the `false` return value.

As a sidenote, to really know what's inside a variable, you can use [`var_dump`](http://php.net/var_dump).

As a bnus, used with [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/), it'll get you a nice-formated output ;-)

Comment: I also recommend use of `var_dump` because many of developers even don't know that this function exist in `PHP`.

Answer (score 7):

0000-00-00 is not a valid date.

date() gives an output because it interprets the input time as 0 and compensates for the timezone of your server, I'd assume.  I'd bet that `date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime(...))` would give 1970-01-01 2:00

Comment: To further elaborate the `strtotime` function is returning boolean false. Just try to `var_dump` the result from it. You need to provide a proper string to `strtotime`.

Answer (score -2):

You are mistaking `strtotime()` for `time()`.

`strtotime` is literally string to time, it needs a string to convert..... to time.

> Returns a timestamp on success, `FALSE` otherwise. Previous to PHP 5.1.0, this function would return `-1` on failure.

So it is failing to validate that time string.